# Responsively change div size while aligning with another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

For the last couple days I've been trying to get my CSS to work, but whenever I fix one thing I seem to break another. I have this codepen with a main div containing chat_bubble and character_image.

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- chat_bubble should fill 70% of the vertical and horizontal space within main.
- When screen width is over 700px:

1. character_image should be to the right of chat_bubble, bottom-left aligned.
2. character_image should not be cropped or extend off the screen.
3. character_image should scale maintaining aspect ratio filling up to 100% of the height of chat_bubble without extending past it or shrinking the size of chat_bubble.

- When screen width is under 700px:

1. character_image should change to another image (I tried to use background-image to do this but couldn't get it to show, I'm thinking of using multiple image tags in the html and hiding/showing them individually).
2. character_image should be below chat_bubble, upper-right aligned.
3. character_image should take up 30% of the vertical height within main.
4. chat_bubble should take up the remaining vertical space, and 100% of the horizontal space within main.

I know I need to use media queries to do it, but I am struggling to think about the logic and what options each div container needs. Right now character_image is a fixed size and creates a scroll bar when the screen isn't large enough. And when I do fix one of the above requirements, I always cause something else to break.

Here's my CSS so far:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Benne', serif;
    font-size: 10vh;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}

#question {
    font-size: 16px; /* fallback */
    font-size: clamp(1em, 5vw, 10vh);
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    height: 20%;
}

.btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5vh;
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

.start-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#chat_bubble    {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background: ghostwhite !important;
    float: left;
}

#character_image  {
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#question-text {
    height:50%;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using flex with chat_bubble & character_image?

Comment: I just watched a guide on using flex-box and tried using it, but all I did was mess up my code even more. Now I can't even get character_image to appear under chat_bubble when the screen is smaller, or to get character_image to scale. I think I'm probably going to have to pay someone to do this for me at this point. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second `<img>` tag inside character image, give one `id="char_1"`, and the other `id="char_2"` and try this css:

```css
#main {
  display: flex; /* Use flexbox */
  flex-direction: row; /* Flex horizontally */
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#chat_bubble {
    width: 70vw; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport width */
    height: 70vh; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport height */
}

#character_image  {
    float: none; /* undo float */
    flex-shrink: 1; /* let character image shrink */
    height: 70vh; /* Make character_image 70% of viewport height */
}

#character_image img {
  height: 100%; 
}

#char_1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
#char_2 {
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width:700px) {
  #main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #chat_bubble {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  #character_image {
    height: 30vh;
  }
  #char_1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #char_2 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I use that HTML and CSS, it looks completely unformatted and breaks entirely. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I updated my codepen with your code, and I added the image tags like this:

<div id="character_image">
        <img id="char_1" src="https://i.imgur.com/7eYWqqo.png" alt="">
                                                                     <img id="char_2" src="https://i.imgur.com/ixM8TtU.png" alt="">
    </div>

Comment: And this is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

Comment: You deleted all your CSS. Just put it back.

Comment: I just checked and the CSS is there. And there don't seem to be any errors. Is it showing no CSS when you look at it? That's really weird, I don't understand.

Comment: I just checked on another device too and the CSS is there. Which part is missing?

Comment: Your CSS, you've only got the CSS I wrote.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly.